# Stuck with Sinatra install on "Ruby The Hard Way" exercise 50

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am almost finished with **Ruby The Hard Way**, but in Exercise 50 I am completely stuck.

In the exercise I am told to install Sinatra with the command:

```
sudo gem install sinatra
```

However, when I do this in my Terminal I am asked for a password. In the exercise it shows how the password prompt will be output, but there's no information about what password to enter.

When I try to use the command:

```
gem install sinatra
```

the Terminal tells me that I don't have write permissions for the Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Can someone explain to me what is going on and how I can install Sinatra on to my Mac?

Answer (score 2):

That should be the password you use when you login in your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

That is the password on your mac. You won't see anything when you are typing.